# How to copy data from pgAdmin without double quotes around the values

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have the below query to convert geometry into GeoJSON format.

```
select ST_ASGEOJSON(POLYGON_GEOMETRY) from "POC"."POLYGON_PLN";
```

output:

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[10.3986007,47.95355213],[10.39885819,47.95386829],[10.39924443,47.95400241],[10.39955914,47.95422277],[10.39967358,47.95436647][10.3986007,47.95355213]]]}
```

The output is fine, But when I tried to copy the output within pgAdmin 4 (or) when I refer this output for some other thing, I am getting the quotations at beginning and end.

Please suggest a way to remove these quotations.

Comment: I am using pgadmin4. Just copying the output and paste in some notepad file.

Comment: In pgadmin 3 in Options -> Query tool -> Results grid, you can configure that. So look for a similar option in pgadmin 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the quote character used in copy-pasted results via the pgAdmin settings.

Open File->Preferences from the menu, then navigate to "Query Tool"->"Results grid", and change the "Result copy quote character" as needed.

Answer (score 11):

In File->Preferences, navigate to "Query Tool"->"Results grid"
change the "Result copy quoting" dropdown to None

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was download data to CSV file so I need change in menu File-> Preferences then navigate to "Query Tool"-> "CSV/TXT Output" and change the "CSV quoting" to “None”.